# How do you pronounce the word "array" in Australian English?

Tags: pronunciation, accent, australian-english

I am learning accents (differences in pronunciation), and I was wondering how to pronounce the word "array" in Australian English, and how it's pronounced in other variants of the language. Is it `AH-ray` or `uh-ray`, and which variant does the other belong to?

Comment: Do you have any specific reason you're asking about *array*? Have you heard an Australian pronounce it strangely?

Comment: No, I'm learning programming as well, and my teacher pronounces it differently to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Australian Oxford Dictionary* (2nd ed.)](http://www.oxfordreference.com/abstract/10.1093/acref/9780195517965.001.0001/m-en_au-msdict-00001-0003070) has **/əˈreɪ/**, which is the usual pronunciation of *array* in both British and American English, so I have no reason to assume it's pronounced any differently in Australian English. (Phonemically, that is. The exact quality of the vowels would of course differ slightly or considerably depending on speaker.)

You can confirm this by listening to [videos on YouTube](https://youglish.com/search/array/aus) (although these must be taken with a grain of salt because not all of them must be Australian speakers).

(Ideally, I should consult the [*Macquarie Dictionary*](https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/), which is the authority on Australian English, but I do not have access to it at the moment.)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! (I have the Macquarie - should have checked)